# My pagination code is not working

Tags: php, mysql

This is my pagination code.It displaying 20 images in first page and its not moving link to second page.My pagination code is not working.Could you please go through my code and give me your suggestions,Thank you.

**Controller**

```
                public function onSectorClick() {
                        $id = $_GET["id"];

                        $this->session->set_userdata('sub1category_id', $_GET['id']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('sub1category_name', $_GET['name']);
                        $this->onSectorClickCopy();
                    }

                    public function onSectorClickCopy(){                            
                        $this->load->helper('url');                          

                        $data['ListMenuLevel1'] = $this->Categories_model->listsector1();

                        $config = array();
                        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/welcome/onSectorClickCopy?id=".$this->session->userdata('sub1category_id')."&name=".$this->session->userdata('sub1category_name');
                        $total_row = $this->productdisplay_model->record_count($this->session->userdata('sub1category_id'));
                        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
                        $config['per_page'] = 20;
                        //$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
                        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
                        //$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
                        //$config['reuse_query_string'] = FALSE;
                        $config['num_links'] = 1;
                        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
                        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
                        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
                        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
                        $this->load->library('pagination');
                        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                        /* if($this->uri->segment(3)){
                          $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
                          }
                          else{
                          $page = 1;
                          } */
                        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1);
                        //$offset = $config['per_page']*$page;

                        $offset = (($config['per_page']) * ($page - 1)) + 1;
                        $limit = $config['per_page'] * $page;
                        $data['sub1products'] = $this->productdisplay_model->sub1Productsmenu($this->session->userdata('sub1category_id'),$limit, $offset);
                        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
                        $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);

                        $this->load->view('productlist', $data);                           
                    }
                }
```

**Model**

```
            <?php

            class productdisplay_model extends CI_Model {

                function __construct() {
                    parent::__construct();
                }
             public function record_count($id) {
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('sub1_category');
                    $this->db->where('main_categoryid_fk', $id);
                    $this->db->order_by("sub1_category.main_categoryid_fk ");
                    $query = $this->db->get();
                    return  $query->num_rows();                       
                }              

                public function sub1Productsmenu($id,$limit, $offset){                        
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('sub1_category');
                    $this->db->where('main_categoryid_fk', $id);
                    $this->db->order_by("sub1_category.main_categoryid_fk ");
                    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
                    return $this->db->get()->result();                        
                }

                public function sub1Productfetch($id) {                        
                    $query = $this->db->select('product_image,sub1_category_name,product_description');
                    $this->db->from('sub3_category');
                    $this->db->join('sub2_category', 'sub3_category.sub2_categoryid_fk=sub2_category.id', 'left');
                    $this->db->join('sub1_category', 'sub2_category.sub1_categoryid_fk=sub1_category.id', 'left');
                    //$this->db->join('maincategory', 'sub1_category.main_categoryid_fk=maincategory.id', 'left');
                    $this->db->where('sub1_category.id',$id);

                    //$this->db->order_by('rand()');
                    $this->db->limit(1);              

                    return $this->db->get()->result();                  
                }
            }
```

**View**

```
     <div class="center">
                <ul class="pagination">
                     <?php
                    foreach ($links as $link) {
                        echo "<li>" . $link . "</li>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Here's a valuable suggestion: Please post a **minimal** amount of code that reproduces your problem. Dumping your whole app here is not helping, it just confuses the issue. Narrowing down the amount of code you post might actually help you find the problem, too. It's never a bad thing.

Comment: simply debug the mysql query and check the limit and offset.

Comment: Yes I debug the sql query and checked for offset and limit its working fine.But in first page displaying 20 images and after that the link doesn't goes to second page.

Comment: what url is generated for second page?

Comment: secondlink:http://localhost/terasukhintrade/index.php/welcome/onSectorClickCopy?id=1&name=agriculture/2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination is not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479637/pagination-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 0):

This provides you to retrieve information from your URI strings

```
$this->uri->segment(n); // n=1 for controller, n=2 for method, etc
```

consider this example http://www.domainname.com/index.php/blog/language/php/function

it will return

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // blog
$this->uri->segment(2); // language
$this->uri->segment(3); // php
$this->uri->segment(4); // function
```

According to your url : http://localhost/terasukhintrade/index.php/welcome/onSectorClickCopy?id=1&name=agriculture/2

$this->uri->segment(3) gets? // try to debug yourself

But in your case, who have to fetch the last uri segment.

**Alternate 1**

```
$last = end($this->uri->segments); 
//Where, segments is a class variable.
```

**Alternate 2**

```
$last = end($this->uri->segment_array());
```

**Alternate 3**

```
$total = $this->uri->total_segments();
$last = $this->uri->segment($total);
```

Update `$page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 1);` to `($this->uri->segment($total) != '' ? $this->uri->segment($total) : 1); // as per alternative 3`

Comment: Thanks a lot.I come to know  the bug in my code.The bug is base_url,I given session id in url.